# How to Add checkboxes for default billing/shipping address and show as check/uncheck

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, address

Currently `Billing` and `Shipping` address don't have checkboxes to
select, to change it from `Billing to Shipping` or `Shipping to Billing`.
It only shows a `message info`.

So, I want to be checkboxes as same as an `additional address` form.
So that user change

> Billing Address -> Shipping Address
>
> Shipping Address -> Billing Address

The problem is how can I get the `Use as my default billing address` checkbox selected when the user edits Billing Address and vice versa for Shipping Address.

*Old Code*

```
 <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
        <div class="message info">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__("It's a default billing address.")) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
        <div class="field choice set shipping">
            <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox">
            <label class="label" for="primary_billing">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1">
    <?php endif; ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
  <?php endif; ?>
```

*Changed Code*

```
 <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
        <div class="field choice set billing">
            <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox">
            <label class="label" for="primary_billing">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
        <div class="field choice set billing">
            <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox">
            <label class="label" for="primary_billing">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
     <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
  <?php endif; ?>
```